# Align Text in middle vertically

Tags: html, css

I am not able to vertically align middle some text using the position absolute method.
[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/9jugdtqx/)

HTML

```
    <div class="heighted">
    <div class="middle-wrapper">
        <span class="middle">text to be vertically aligned in the middle</span>
    </div>
</div>
<hr/>
<div class="heighted">
    <div class="middle-wrapper">
        <img class="middle" src="http://www.google.com/homepage/images/google_favicon_64.png" />
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
    .heighted {
    background: gray;
    height: 100px;
}
.middle-wrapper {
    height: 100%;
    position: relative;
}
.middle {
    bottom: 0;
    margin: auto;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
}
```

I am getting Stack Overflow error when adding code, it might be a bug in Stack Overflow, so please follow the link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try `display:table-cell;` and use `vertical-align:middle;`

Check how amazing and optimize:
http://jsfiddle.net/9jugdtqx/2/

and:
http://jsfiddle.net/9jugdtqx/3/

Comment: Nice, it works, but I would also like to know why my example is not working.

Comment: @Jack margin auto not working with height and buttom.. it's only work with right and left.. try this.. I used percentage value for Top property http://jsfiddle.net/9jugdtqx/8/

Answer (score 1):

Set `line-height: 100px;` to `.heighted` or `.middle-wrapper` or `.middle` - **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/9jugdtqx/1/)**

**CSS:**

```
.heighted {
    background: gray;
    height: 100px;
    line-height: 100px;
}
.middle-wrapper {
    height: 100%;
    position: relative;
}
.middle {
    bottom: 0;
    margin: auto;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<div class="heighted">
    <div class="middle-wrapper">
        <span class="middle">text to be vertically aligned in the middle</span>
    </div>
</div>
<hr/>
<div class="heighted">
    <div class="middle-wrapper">
        <img class="middle" src="http://www.google.com/homepage/images/google_favicon_64.png" />
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The text can also be long, or the screen size may get reduced to mobile, which will make it to break. Check this out http://jsfiddle.net/9jugdtqx/5/

Comment: @Jack As per your fiddle `display:table-cell;` is the best approach, but should tell me that before. lol...